# extends ImageView android?

Tags: android, imageview, extends

How can I extend `ImageView`, so that I can use in my code `findViewById`?
I just got 25 `ImageView`and I need after click on one to get some value.
I know that I have to create new class, extends `ImageView` and add constructors, but when I try to implement as `findViewById`, I got error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
    at com.emirates.worldstreets.explore.FashionTab.setUpStars(FashionTab.java:457)
    at com.emirates.worldstreets.explore.FashionTab.fillUpDetails(FashionTab.java:376)
    at com.emirates.worldstreets.explore.FashionTab.access$8(FashionTab.java:326)
    at com.emirates.worldstreets.explore.FashionTab$4.onItemClick(FashionTab.java:317)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: paste the code that u have done...

Comment: When you declare it in the XML layout file it must also be the same custom view that you made, not the ImageView type. Remember to include the full package path as the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in code you use findViewById the same way you would with a normal ImageView but with a cast to your custom view

```
MyImageView myImageView = (MyImageView)findViewById(R.id.name);
```

in xml you need to specify the full path of the class

```
<com.package.name.MyImageView 
    android:id="@+id/name"
    .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

to find a view using `findViewById`, it must have been defined inside a .xml file.